# Solve the problem of the Arabic language in Python PYAUTOGUI

Tags: python, hide, arabic, pyautogui

I have been trying to write Arabic text with pyautogui but the text appears blank and nothing prints

Any help please because I was unable to search

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite("مرحبا")
```